password change needed for all users
I have inherited a website that was created for a POA.  Everyone in the POA has the same username and password to access the website.  I need to change password, but can't figure out how.  And I'm not very computer savvy!!  Help

If you are talking about not too many users: You can navigate to the Users section in the sidebar of the CMS. If you navigate to a specific user, you can change a password or tell them to change the password on the next login. Does that work for you?
